# FlinkKafkaConsumer how to stop pulling messages

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink application that reads from a single Kafka topic.
I am trying to stop FlinkKafkaConsumer to stop pulling messages.
My final goal is to build a method to deploy my Flink application from time to time without downtime at all - [how to deploy a new job without downtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476638/how-to-deploy-a-new-job-without-downtime).

I have tried to use "kafkaConsumer.close()" but that does not work. I am trying to stop the consumer from pulling new messages without killing the entire Job, at the same time I will upload a new Job with the updated code that reads from the same topic.
How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to send a special 'switch' message on all partitions of the kafka topic? Then you could override `isEndOfStream(T nextElement)` in your Kafka `DeserializationSchema`, and have your new job instance start working after the last switch message

Comment: Yes, that would work. I've tested this solution and it does work. Is it a good practice or a hack ? what is the reason for the Flink API to not have the ability to disconnect from a source ? anyway, about the zero-downtime switch of a Flink application, i understand that due to the stateful nature of a Flink application i cannot share same state between two Jobs

Comment: You're right about the state sharing. That said, the fact that you're avoiding the delay of using Flink's savepoint and job restart/update methods suggests that you probably can't afford the time hit of synchronizing state between the two jobs, even if you were to set up some kind of external state you could hit some nasty consistency problems.

TBH, the 'Best Practice' is probably to keep the startup time on your job short enough that you can afford the hit. The fault tolerance of Flink is not zero downtime like you want, so if a host dies or something you'll still get downtime